# Sending .caf to server with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, asihttprequest

I am using AVAssetReader to create a .caf file that can play locally on my computer. However, when I try to upload the .caf to a server, the uploaded file can no longer be read. Here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"Posting to server");
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serverString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setData:songData
    withFileName:@"exported.caf"
  andContentType:@"audio/x-caf"
          forKey:@"musicfile"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Interesting, when I do the following, the generated file works on my computer:

```
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.caf"];
[songData writeToFile:storePath atomically:NO];
```

Do I have to append some type of header to the musicData to get the .caf to be formatted properly?

Comment: It sounds like a sever-side problem. Does the uploaded file actually gets saved on the server? 

Also, I'd not send the storepath to the server, but have the server decide where to store. Otherwise somebody can overwrite system files using a http request.

Comment: Btw, ASIHTTPRequest isn't supported/developed any more. Consider alternative such as AFNetworking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some trouble shooting notes to identify the problem:

1. ensure that you are playing the song in the server using the exact same audio reader app that you used to play it locally (ie eliminate the possibility that the server audio app has the appropriate decoder to read a `.caf` file. You can easily troubleshoot that by trying to play an original (ie one you didn't create yourself, one that's proven to work) `.caf` file on the remote server.
2. whenever you face a problem that you have trouble identifying the cause.. then take a step back and use first principles. In this case.. download a hex editor like [hexfiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) and compare the file you got locally that can be read with the one on the server.. if you see any discrepancy in values, that means that the values got messed up during the transfer. This happens because of the whole **big endian/ small endian** network transfer [issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (you can find a  good discussion of what big/small endian means [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12910/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-3), you resolve this issue by using functions like [CFSwapInt16BigToHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001449-CH201-DontLinkElementID_10) etc (used as an example.. it may not be the one you end up having to use).
3. you are using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) API.. which is a wrapper around the CFNetwork API. It's stated purpose is to make your life easier, but in this case if too much is hidden under the hood (ie you can't easily debug the problem), that purpose is no longer fulfilled. If that's the case, I suggest you jump a layer deeper and use [CFNetwork API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html) directly. (It's not that hard, and is definitely easier to debug).

Comment: According to hex fiend it seems like my program is appending the file name to the beginning of the .caf file. When I remove the first 22 bytes it works, but I wonder if there is a better way of saving the file that doesn't do this?

Comment: well obviously you don't want to append a file name to data erroneously only to take it out later.. it's misleading and inefficient. I suspect it has to do with this method `[request setData:songData
    withFileName:@"exported.caf"
  andContentType:@"audio/x-caf"
          forKey:@"musicfile"];` but that's just a wild guess.. play around with the parameters etc and I'm sure you'll figure it out. Anyways you got it working! will i get the correct answer? :D